# Dynamic Mvc route

Tags: url, model-view-controller

I know there is a lot topics with the same name, but none of those I've found so far, have provided the answer I need.

I'm creating a "dropbox" site for my students to upload their projects on when they have to submit them to me.

The thing is that the students are able to create folders and I would like(if possible) to display the url based on the "folders" they are able to create on the website.

Folders could look like.

- Home
- Project

  - Project 1

    - Project 1 v1
    - Project 1 v2

      - And so on.
  - project 2
- Submit

Basic the path could be short or long depends on the folder level.
Like : `Home` or `Project/Project-1-v1/` or `Project/Project-1-v1/Upload/Final`

Is there a way to create a dynamic `url/action` that accept any of the above Path's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done fairly easy.

My `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute("CatchALL", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

My `Controller`

```
[Route("Home/{*catchall}")]
    public ActionResult Part(string catchall)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If this was the url: `http://stackoverflow.com/Home/36542665/dynamic-mvc-route` catchall would contain = `36542665/dynamic-mvc-route`